# Is there a strategy in which I can guess $x \sim U(1, 100)$ better than $E[N] = 50$ where $N$ is the number of guesses?

Tags: probability, expected-value

Consider a random number drawn uniformly from $U(1,100)$. You keep guessing until you get the right number, and for each guess, you are not given any information either than that the guess is right or wrong (if you're told the number you guessed is greater or smaller than the actual number, then you can use a binary search approach, and I believe you can get the right answer in at most $\lfloor \log_2(100) \rfloor + 1$ tries, but we're not given that info). Let $N$ be the number of guesses it took to guess the right number.

Is there a strategy in which $E[N] < 50$?

For any strategy that guesses without replacement (i.e., don't be dumb and guess the same number that you already guessed), I believe $E[N] = 50$.

You could guess in consecutive increasing order from 1....100, or from consecutive decreasing order from 100...1, or whatever permutation of $\{1,2,\ldots, 100\}$ you want, I think the expectation will always be 50.

I don't think there exists a guessing strategy with $E[N] < 50$. What do you guys think?

Comment: Absolutely agree, because each wrong guess conveys absolutely no information other than that the specific guess was wrong.

Comment: As long as you are given no information after any of your guesses, there is no better method than a simple exhaustive search. However, if after a guess you are told whether your guess is too high or too low, you can do a midpoint type search in which case you can expect the average number of guesses to be $\log_2(100)$.

Comment: What if rather than thinking about this purely as an interval $(0,100)$, what if we thought of each integer (assuming the problem is talking about strictly integers) in the interval as a random sample and removed one entry with each incorrect guess, reindexing this to $(0,99)$ to get the one hundred samples? For example, if the first guess was $65$ and that wasn't the correct number, we remove that from our list of possibilities and shrink the interval to $(0,99)$, representing only 99 possibilities remaining.

Comment: @SprNtndoChlmrs That's affectively what you're doing when you're guessing without replacement. You just cycle through a list of distinct numbers until you get the right one, but on, average, that's always 50 no matter what order you guess in because the target is uniformly distributed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!